# why $(1,1)$ have infinite order?

Tags: group-theory

Prove the set of elements of the direct product $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$ of infinite order together with the identity is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$.

My attempt : Answer  is given [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Efelix077/download/sec2.pdf) see Page No .$2$

It is written that $(1,1)$ and $(-1,n)$ have  infinite order and the  product $(1,1) +(-1,0)=(0,1)$
have  finite order

**My confusion** : why $(1,1)$  have  infinite order ?

Here $(1,1)^n =(1,1)$   so  i think $(1,1)$ have finite order

Comment: $(1,1)^n = (n,0)$, not $(1,1)$. The operation is addition, not multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group operation on $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is **componentwise addition**. So e.g. setting $n=3$ we have $$(1,1)+(1,1)=(2,2)\mbox{ and } (1,1)+(1,1)+(1,1)=(3,0).$$

It should be clear that no matter what $n$ is, adding $(1,1)$ to itself over and over again will never reach the additive identity $(0,0)$ since the left coordinate will just keep growing. (Exponent notation makes this a bit less clear; typically, for groups known to be abelian we use *multiplicative* notation instead, so e.g. "$3(1,1)=(3,0)$" in the above exaple.)

In particular, adding $(1,1)$ to itself $n$ times in $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ will yield $$(n,0)$$ which is not the same as $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

For that example one is using *addition* on each factor of the direct product. Note you could deduce that multiplication was *not* the operation being used, since the first factor is not a group under multiplication.

Comment: Neither the second factor.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, noticed that later. Under multiplication, second factor has no inverse for the zero element of $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}.$